# Azure Functions DurableFunction Status output is Pascal cased

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am using an Azure Durable Functions Starter which returns a `CreateCheckStatusResponse`.  The client polls the provided URL until the `runtimeStatus` is "Completed" and uses the output.  In my other .netcore applications the endpoints return JSON is camel case; however, this Output property has it in Pascal - how can I change this behavior in my functions app?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization" library to convert the output of the function app from pascal case to camel case.

Here is the reference thread about converting the serial object to [camel case in http trigger functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638174/http-triggers-in-azure-functions-serializing-objects-in-camelcase)

Comment: My case is slightly different because I'm using `CreateCheckStatusResponse` which does not have an overload for using that configuration.  However, one of the other responses (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53681329/16040368) was exactly what I needed.